# xargs | Use input as command

Tags: shell, xargs, fish

I would have assumed that following examples work perfectly fine.

```
$ which -a python python3 pip | xargs -I {} {} --version
No '{}' such file or folder
$ which -a python python3 pip | xargs -I _ _ --version
No '_' such file or folder
$ which -a python python3 pip | xargs -I py py --version
No 'py' such file or folder
```

But they don't work at all when I run it interactively it doesn't even substitute the string. I see no note in manual page regarding a special case in first position. Why does this not work?

```
$ which -a python python3 pip | xargs -I py -p eval py --version
eval ~/.pyenv/shims/python --version?...y
xargs: eval: No such file or directory
```

This is even more surprising because it does substitute correctly.

How can I use the argument in first place? I don't want to use `... -I py sh -c "py --version"` because this will create a new sub-process. I wish to know how to eval command in current env.

Comment: not much use to most people, but it looks like [map](https://github.com/sitaramc/map), my personal replacement for xargs works fine: `which -a python python3 | map -1 % --version` (I don't have pip)

Comment: @sitaram thx! Always on the lookout for improvements on "old age gran-daddy" tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `xargs -I replstr utility arguments`, [POSIX requires](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/xargs.html) that the `replstr` be only substituted in the `arguments`, not `utility`. GNU `xargs` is compliant in that regard (busybox `xargs` is not).

To work around it, you can use `env` as the utility:

```
which -a ... | xargs -I cmd xargs env cmd --version
```

(chokes on leading whitespace, backslash, single quote, double quote, newline, possibly sequences of bytes nor forming valid characters, because of the way `xargs` interprets its input).

Or better:

```
for cmd in (which -a ...)
  $cmd --version
end
```

Which would limit problematic characters in file names to newline only.

In any case, you can't and don't want to use `eval` here. `eval` is the shell builtin (special builtin in POSIX shells) command to interpret shell code, not to run commands. `xargs` is an external command to the shell, so it cannot run builtins of your shell or of any shell without starting an interpreter of that shell like with:

```
which -a ... |
  xargs -rd '\n' sh -c 'for cmd do "$cmd" --version; done' sh
```

Using `sh` instead of `fish` here as AFAIK `fish` inline scripts can't take arguments. But still *not* using `eval` here which wouldn't make sense as we don't want those file names to be interpreted as shell code.

Also using `-rd '\n'` which is GNU-specific, but doesn't have all the issues of `-I`, to pass the full contents of all lines as separate arguments to the utility (here `sh`).